# Initialize NSArray in init function of a class

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {

        self.mdAudios = [NSMutableArray array];
        self.mdPhotos = [NSMutableArray array];
        self.mdVideos = [NSMutableArray array];
        self.mdVrs = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Instruments says my custom init function is leaking memory, is it?

Comment: My guess: you would be re-initializing it again, somewhere in your code.

Comment: I don't see any memory leak there. Make sure that, if you're not using ARC, in your dealloc method, you set those properties to nil.

Comment: Show the declaration of this class (i.e. the header file).

Comment: Don't use self.argv in init method. Please use _argv =  someValue.

Comment: Also use double parens: `if ((self = [super init]))`